# windows permissions and uac managed .NET

Tags: .net, windows, permissions, uac, account

Consider a .NET managed application. No special permission is need to add a key to HKCU, correct?

Whether the user is a standard user, or an administrator, no special permission settings are needed?

What happens if the application tries to add a key to HKLM? Does the user need to be an administrator? Does the UAC prompt appear?

Answer (score 0):

No special permission is needed to modify HKCU, any user can modify their own registry branch.

If you attempt to modify HKLM, you need to have administrator privileges. The `RegCreateKey` operation will fail<sup>1</sup> if you are a standard user. The UAC prompt will not appear simply because the application tried to write to a protected location.

This is the same behaviour you would see in Windows XP. The operation will fail with access denied.

If your application needs to write to HKLM, then you can either:

- mark your application to always run as an administrator (bad)
- launch a copy of your application using the `ShellExecute` **runas** verb, so the user can temporarily elevate to perform the operation that requires administrative access (better)
- not write to HKLM (best)

Your application should not be writing to HKLM. If you have items you need to configure, they should be done at install-time (when your installer will have permission to create keys in HKLM).

The other alternative is to have your application's installer the security settings of the HKLM branch you need to write go. Grant **Full Control** to **Everyone**. That way everyone can modify the HKLM branch you need to alter.